# Subdomain Redirect

Tags: .htaccess

I want write a rule in .htaccess for redirecting

```
http://www.dir.domain.com
http://dir.domain.com
http://www.domain.com/dir
```

these should redirect to

```
http://domain.com/dir
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Do you currently have a `*.domain.com` catchall redirecting to your DOCROOT for `domain.com`?  What type of service do you have? A VPS or a shared service, if the latter is it cPanel or webadmin enabled.  What you are asking is doable but the answer varies depending on what you tell us.

Comment: I have a domain and a subdomain in a shared service. Here im talking about my subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to use an `.htaccess` file in your DOCROOT

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase   /

RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}    ^(www\.)?dir\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule   ^.*             http://domain.com/dir/$0     [R=301,L]

RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}    ^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule   ^dir/.*         http://domain.com/$0         [R=301,L]
```

Note that this is doing a 301 redirect -- that is the server tells the browser that this is a permanent redirect and the browser caches this redirect.

You can also do an internal redirect where this mapping is done silently at the server end by tweaking flags.

This assumes that your shared service is using Apache, if its using IIS, then you need to do something similar with the web.config

Comment: >RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.dir.domain.com [NC]
>RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/dir/$1 [L,R=301]
>RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dir.domain.com [NC]
>RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/dir/$1 [L,R=301]    >RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dir.domain.com [NC]
>RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/dir/$1 [L,R=301] > If im adding this code on /dir/.htaccess then it is redirecting >[http://dir.domain.com]
>[http://www.domain.com/dir] to [http://domain.com/dir] >but it is not redirecting [http://www.dir.domain.com] @TerryE

Comment: @HDTV, note the tweak on Cond1  -- also edit your Q to add info like this.

Answer (score 0):

***You can try:***

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www).+)\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.com/%1 [L,NE]
```

Please change domain by your domain, when you enter sub1.domain.com then it will redirect to domain.com/sub1, when you enter sub2.domain.com then it will redirect to domain.com/sub2 ....

Comment: Please give detail answer