# How to create subdomain using CakePHP

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, subdomain

What I want:

```
http://mydomain.com/view/paris -> http://paris.mydomain.com
http://mydomain.com/view/new-york -> http://new-york.mydomain.com
etc
```

How can I make it using .htaccess, or tell me another solution if it exists.

**P.S.** Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

Please read it

http://pastebin.com/dJVj80mE

http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/4046649.htm

[Subdomain Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446214/subdomain-redirect)

// subdomain component for cakephp that depends on a model

https://gist.github.com/1498851

or try

Redirect subdomain to CakePHP action

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).myserver.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://myserver.com/m/%1/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+).myserver.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (?!^m/$)^.*$ http://myserver.com/m/sites/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,P]
```

Or

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase   /

RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}    ^(www\.)?dir\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule   ^.*             http://domain.com/dir/$0     [R=301,L]

RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}    ^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule   ^dir/.*         http://domain.com/$0         [R=301,L]
```

Comment: So, it's will be redirect www.paris.mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com/view/paris ? @abidhussain

Comment: I haven't created the subdomain. I mean, how make that http://mydomain.com/view/paris will redirect http://paris.mydomain.com  , http://mydomain.com/view/new-york to http://new-york.mydomain.com and so on. @abidhussain

Answer (score 0):

As CakePHP API documentation states:
http://api12.cakephp.org/class/controller#method-Controllerredirect

you could able to supply the URL of your sub domain to the redirect method:

```
$this->redirect('http://paris.mydomain.com');
```